# BigQuery timestamp in mm:ss

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a query which gives me timestamps in the below format:

2020-10-25 09:58:21.479 UTC

2020-10-25 10:18:22.737105 UTC

What I would like to do is calculate the difference between the two times and displayed in mm:ss format? For my example, the output would be 20:01

```
SELECT
MIN(ts) AS session_start_time,
MAX(ts) AS session_end_time,
FROM(
SELECT
  event_date AS date,
  user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
  event_name,
  key,
  value,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS ts,
FROM
  `table _name`,
  UNNEST (event_params) AS event_params
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20201025"
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND event_name != 'view_search_results'
  AND user_pseudo_id = '4B132ED3654C4293B9820D8203282B0D'
ORDER BY ts ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result as a time using:

```
select time_add(time '00:00:00', interval timestamp_diff(max(ts), min(ts), millisecond) millisecond)
```

Then if you want this as a string in a particular format:

```
select time_format('%M:%S', time_add(time '00:00:00', interval timestamp_diff(max(ts), min(ts), millisecond) millisecond))
```